# Contact Form Allowing Blank Form Submissions

Tags: javascript, forms, zurb-foundation

I have a PHP contact form on my site and am using Zurb Foundation with Abide to ensure completed forms. If I skip through the form fields, the error messages come up, but it still allows a blank and/or incomplete form to be submitted. Is there a way to prevent submission unless there is a completed form?

edit to get code samples displaying correctly

HTML:

```
   <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns" id="form-right">
     <form id="myForm" data-abide="ajax">
        <div class="contactform">
           <div class="name-field">
           <label>Your name <small>required</small>
           <input id="name" type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
           <small class="error">Hi I'm Parker. What's your name?</small>
           </label>
           </div>
           <div class="email-field">
           <label>Email <small>required</small>
           <input id="email" type="email" required>
           <small class="error">Oops, you forgot your email.</small>
           </label>
           </div>
           <div class="text-field">
           <label>Message <small>required</small>
           </label>
           <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
           <small class="error">I see you're the quiet type. How about a short message?</small>
           </div>
           <!--<button type="submit">Submit</button>-->
           <input type="submit" name="sendbutton" id="sendbutton" class="sendbutton button radius" value="Submit" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>    
$('#myForm')
.on('submit', function () {
var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var message = $("textarea#message").val();

//Data for response
var dataString = 'name=' + name +
    '&email=' + email +
    '&message=' + message;

//Begin Ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"php/mail.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('.contactform').html("<div id='thanks'></div>");
            $('#thanks').html("<h2>Thanks!</h2>")
            .append("<p>Glad to hear from you "+ name +"! I'll be in touch soon.</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500);
    },
    }); //ajax call
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

```
$('#myForm').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
    // Handle the submission of the form
});
```

Comment: Thanks @dave! I read the docs several times but somehow missed that page. Was going off the form docs. Thanks for the help, works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, validate your variables before you generate the dataString:

```
var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var message = $("textarea#message").val();

if (name && email && message) {

    // Continue from here

} else {

    // Display a warning
}
```

You might want to look at http://jqueryvalidation.org/ for more validation stuff on the client side, i.E. for email addresses.